# How to create a error message for stack over/underflow

Tags: python

I am new to programming, and I am not sure how to figure this out.

I want to raise an error when an integer goes over the max integer ... so I imported `sys` ... The max integer is `2147483647` and the min is `-2147483648`. I am creating a list using the Fibonacci sequence so I tried to write some code that said:

```
if i > 2147483647:
    print "Overflow Error"
```

... and likewise for the minimum value. However, it does not do anything and I am still able to list numbers past `2147483647`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the *complete* [example](http://sscce.org). This is just a print, which of course has no effect to the logic of the program.

Comment: Are you saying it's not crashing _and_ it's not printing your message? In that case, simply debug your code.

Comment: Python integers can be as large as memory allows, actually. Try it; `import sys; sys.maxint * 2`.

Comment: "max int" only matters if you're working with the system's definition of a C int data type.  (Using an operating system API, interacting with other libraries without good Python wrapper extensions, serializing/deserializing data, etc)

Comment: I smelling a homework problem...

Answer (score 2):

Python long integers have no upper limit, they are only limited to what you can fit in RAM:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint * 2
18446744073709551614L
```

The `sys.maxint` value tells you where python will start to use the `long` type instead of `int` to represent integers; the transition is automatic.

You are not likely to hit that memory limit when calculating fibonacci sequences.

Answer (score 0):

As Martijn said, you won't hit any errors (unless you are dealing with VERY large numbers or lists of a very large size). However, Python doesn't allow you to actually use up all of your memory; it will raise an error if too much memory is used (`MemoryError`).

If you want to set a limit on your input, though:

```
from sys import maxint
if i > maxint: raise ValueError('i cannot exceed 2147483647')
elif i < -1 * maxint: raise ValueError('i must be greater than -2147483647').
```

I don't suggest you raise an `OverflowError`, `ValueError` is more appropriate.

I'm unclear on the question, so if you were trying to check if the list-size was greater than `maxint`:

```
from sys import maxint
if len(i) > maxint: raise ValueError('i cannot exceed 2147483647 elements')
# you don't need a minimum value, as the length cannot be negative
```

If you are trying to check if the max value of the list is greater than `maxint`:

```
from sys import maxint
if max(i) > maxint: raise ValueError('i cannot exceed 2147483647')
```